# A power of a sum in a non-commutative algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras

Let $ A := \mathbb{C}\langle x, y \rangle / ( xy-2 ) $ where $ \mathbb{C}\langle x, y \rangle $ is the free (non-commuative) $ \mathbb{C} $-algebra which is generated by $ x $ and $ y $ and $ ( xy-2 ) $ is the two-sided ideal which generated by the element $ xy-2 $.

Let us also write $ x $ resp. $ y $ for the classes of $ x $ resp. $ y $ in $ A $. Clearly, the elements $ y^k x^l $ form a basis of $ A $ for $ k, l \in \mathbb{N}_0 $. Therefore, there is a presentation
$$ ( x + y )^n = \sum_{k + l = 0, \dots, n} c_{k,l}^{(n)} y^k x^l $$
for any $ n \in \mathbb N_0 $.

**Questions:**
I am interested in the sum of these coefficients, i.e.
$$ S_n = \sum_{k, l} c_{k,l}^{(n)}. $$

1. Is there a general method to compute powers of sums in such algebras?
2. What can be more said about the asymptotic behaviour of $ S_n $ except for the obvious bounds in $(*)$?
3. Does anybody know a context in which this algebra (or more generally the algebra $ \mathbb C\langle x, y \rangle / ( xy - a ) $ for $ a \in \mathbb N $) plays a role?

**Known and maybe helpful:**
As we have two choices in each of the $ n $ factors in $ ( x + y )^n $, (without using the relation $ xy = 2 $) we already count at least $ 2^n $ $ ( x, y ) $-monomials. Moreover, applying the relation $ xy = 2 $ only doubles the coefficient of any of these $ 2^n $ monomials. This provides the lower bound $ 2^n $ for $ S_n $.
One the other hand, mapping $ ( x, y ) \mapsto (\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2) $ yields a morphism $ A \to \mathbb{C} $ of $ \mathbb C $-algebras and gives the upper bound $ 2^{3n/2} $. So, we have the bounds
\begin{align} 2^n \le S_n \le 2^{3n/2}. (*) \end{align}
Furthermore, with some more effort one can show  $ S_n \ll 2^{3n/2} / \sqrt n $ asymptotically as $ n \to \infty $. Anyway, I have the feeling that $ 2^{3n/2} $ is not far off, in the sense that $ (2^{3/2}-\varepsilon)^n / S_n \to 0 $ for any $ \varepsilon > 0 $.

**Approach:**
Let $ \mathbb C^{ \mathbb N } $ be the vector space of sequences with elements in $ \mathbb C $ and $ L, R \in \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb C}( \mathbb C^{ \mathbb N } ) $ be the backward and forward shifts. Then the algebra $ A $ is isomorphic to the sub algebra $ B := \mathbb C\langle L, R \rangle $ of $ \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb C}( \mathbb C^{ \mathbb N } ) $ (consider the map $ ( x, y ) \mapsto ( 2 L, R ) $). I seems to be possible to get $ S_n $ by the action of $ B $ on $ \mathbb C^{\mathbb N } $. But it is computationally involved and unclear whether the so obtained presentation of the $ S_n $ is useful.

**Edit**
As suggested in the comments, here are some additional information which were computed by using MAGMA: For $ n = 0, \dots, 15 $, the values of $ S_n $ are
$$ [ 1, 2, 5, 12, 31, 78, 205, 528, 1403, 3666, 9817, 25908, 69783, 185526, 502005, 1342296 ] $$
and, for $ n = 0, \dots, 5 $ the desired presentations of $ ( x + y )^n $ are
$ [
    1, \\
    x + y, \\
    x^2 + y*x + y^2 + 2, \\
    x^3 + y*x^2 + y^2*x + y^3 + 4*x + 4*y, \\
    x^4 + y*x^3 + y^2*x^2 + y^3*x + y^4 + 6*x^2 + 6*y*x + 6*y^2 + 8, \\
    x^5 + y*x^4 + y^2*x^3 + y^3*x^2 + y^4*x + y^5 + 8*x^3 + 8*y*x^2 + 8*y^2*x + 8*y^3 + 20*x + 20*y
] .$

Comment: Have you checked the sequence on OEIS?

Comment: The usual algebra associated to the forward and backward shift would be the Jacobson algebra or monoid algebra of the bicyclic monoid  given by the relations ab=1. It seems your algebra should be isomorphic by replacing a and b by themselves divided by root 2

Comment: Sorry I meant above replace x, y by themselves divided by root 2.

Comment: Don't you get $2^n$? Your homomorphism to C evaluates on the left to $2^{3n/2}$ and in the right to $2^{n/2}S_n$.  So you get $2^n$ or am I doing something wrong

Comment: It looks like one can get useful recurrences for the polynomial $p_{n}(x,y)=\sum_{k,l\leq n}c^{(n)}_{k,l}y^{k}x^{l}$ where the variables $x,y$ are commutative and $S_{n}=p_{n}(1,1)$.  If this works, I will try to answer after I get some rest.

Comment: @LSpice yes, I checked. It is not known there.

Comment: @Joseph Van Name this is what I did to get the asymptotic bound $ S_n \ll 2^{3n/2} / \sqrt 2 $. After replacing y = 2/x, using the formula $ ( x + 2/x )^n = (\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{2k} 2^{n-k} ) / x^n $ and separating this sum to its principal and non principal part, one wants to evaluate the principal part at 2 and the non principal part at 1. Doing so, leaves one basically with the formula $ S_n = 2  \sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{k} 2^k $. This again behaves asymptotically like $ 2^{3n/2} / \sqrt n $.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2826501/generalized-generating-function-for-binomial-coefficients for the last part

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I think there is a mistake in your argument. The sequence is definitely not $ 2^n $. The problem seems to be that, on the right side, you don't get $ 2^{n/2} S_n = 2^{n/2} \sum c_{k,l}^{(n)} $ but the weighted sum $ 2^{n/2} \sum c_{k,l}^{(n)} 2^{(k+l)/2} $.

Comment: Sorry you are right.  I forgot that k+l is not n.  Shouldn't do these things right before bed

Comment: Any sequence that isn't known by OEIS should be submitted!  Would you mind including the first few terms in your post?  I did it by hand and got 1, 2, 5, 12, 27, but (a) almost surely made some mistakes and (b) even if I didn't, it's way too cumbersome to keep doing by hand.

Comment: @LSpice I have included the first 16 elements of the sequence and the first 6 products in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the sum of the coefficients of the degree-$(n-2k)$ "reduced" monomials $y^ix^j$ in $(x+y)^n$. The degree of a reduced monomial always differs from $n$ by an even number, so this will capture everything. This is clearly of the form $2^k\cdot T(n,k)$ for some unknown function $T$, since each time you reduce the product $xy$ you pick up a factor of $2$. So your sum $S_n$ equals $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} 2^k\cdot T(n,k)$.

Now, I claim that $T(n,k)$ is given by A298637 on the OEIS. This is basically immediate from the definition. From the explicit formula given there, we have $$T(n,k) = \frac{(n+1-2k)^2}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}$$
so that
$$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} 2^k\cdot \frac{(n+1-2k)^2}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}$$
By considering the contribution to the sum for $k=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ we see that this equals $2^{3n/2 - o(1)}$, confirming your suspicion.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is completely correct and was very helpful!

Comment: @diddy Glad to have helped!